# Inherited static method does not use new overridden static attribute

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a c++ class in a header file:

```cpp
class Component {
public:
    static const char identifier = '_';
    static bool represented_by(const std::string& token_str);
};
```

The `represented_by` method is implemented in a separate file:

```cpp
bool Component::represented_by(const std::string &token_str) {
    return token_str.rfind(identifier, 0) == 0;
}
```

When I create an instance of a subclass of `Component` and call `represented_by` with the overridden value of `identifier`, the method still only returns true if the input starts with the identifier defined for the original `Component` class. How can I make it so that it uses the new value of `identifier` instead of the inherited value?

Example:

```cpp
class Resistor: public Component {
public:
    static const char identifier = 'R';
};
```

Output:

```sh
Resistor::represented_by("R1 foo bar 10k")
> 0
Resistor::represented_by("_1 foo bar 10k")
> 1
```

I would expect the output to be the opposite way around.

Comment: Constants don't "partecipate" in inheritance, the `identifier` in `Resistor` is a brand new constant unrelated with `identifier` in `Component`. To get what you want you'd need a virtual function returning a `char` defined in `Component` and overridden.

Comment: in general you cannot override members, only methods can be overriden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect polymorphism behaviour over static members. But as `char` is an integral type, you can use templates:

```
template <char Identifier = '_'>
class Component {
public:
    static const char identifier = Identifier;
    static bool represented_by(const std::string& token_str);
};

template <char Identifier>
bool Component<Identifier>::represented_by(const std::string &token_str) {
    return token_str.rfind(identifier, 0) == 0;
}

class Resistor: public Component<'R'>{};
```